# Moving a div relative to what vertical position you are on a scrollable page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine I have a website that overflows three times the viewport height. I can scroll on this website from top to bottom.

Is it possible to create a div that moves from the top of the viewport to the bottom relative to the amount of the total page that has been scrolled?

Example - Would someone mind helping me achieve something like [this](https://www.lorenzobocchi.com/2017/starbucks/)? Not sure how it was done.

Edit:

```
    var scrollValue;
    var percent; 

    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
                  scrollValue = $("body").scrollTop();
                    percent = (scrollValue / height) * 100;
                    alert(percent);
        });
    });
```

Comment: and... What is problem you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - I'm not sure how to move a div relative to how much of the page has been scrolled. @Bhansa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using jQuery `scrollTop()`. See the [demo at jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

**Idea:**
If you understand the both type of use of this function (with/without args) you can use this same function to get the current scroll position of your custom scrollbar, then trigger your div to be scrolled to the relative scrolling position.

**Alternate Task:** If you want to scroll the custom scrollbar on mousewheel move, I recommend to use [jquery mousewheel plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/)-

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

  if (delta == 1) // going down
  else //going up

  // all kinds of code

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I got a demo working where the div moves to where it should be on the click of a button... any idea how to update it whenever a scroll action occurs? @Partharajdeb

Comment: Have a look at the code I've placed in my edited question. I'm taking the position of the current scrollbar on buttonpress, finding the height of the page and dividing the position of the scrollbar by the total page height to give a percentage down the page of where the scrollbar is sitting. However, I want this to automatically update whenever the user scrolls, because a buttonpress is very unpractical. Would I just have to use timeout to fire the loop thousands of times per second? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I already answered it in the **Alternate Task** part. If mouse wheel move event is detected just get the scrollTop amount and change the position of the custom scroll bar indicator. Hope you got it...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but

`<script src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel.git"></script>`

returns the error:

`Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel.git' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Any idea why? I'm just trying to get the mousewheel function working.

Comment: You are wrong brother. The url you used in the `script` is a git repository not a js file. You should download the plugin from the link below . Then use the `jquery.mousewheel.min.js` file as script file instead of which you did.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/releases/tag/3.1.13